# set the default value to Input type Date - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a project with laravel, i need set default value to input type date.

I use the variable:    value="{{$pedido->entrega}} "

result:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1exn.png)

the problem is that the date is not displayed

in the database is the date

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWpvO.png)

```html
<input type="date"  class="form-control flatpickr flatpickr-input active mb-4" id="entrega" name="entrega"
       value="{{$pedido->entrega}} " 
       min="2018-01-01" max="2025-12-31">
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The flatpickr config is what's needed

```
<input type="date"  class="form-control flatpickr flatpickr-input active mb-4" id="entrega" name="entrega" min="2018-01-01" max="2025-12-31" />

<script>
flatpickr('#entrega',{
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
    defaultDate: ["{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($pedido->entrega)) }} "]
})
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the help but both ways it doesn't work for me

Comment: For the record, if this answer didn't work I would happily delete it, but since it's accepted I cannot. Feel free to unaccept. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="date"  class="form-control" id="date" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
```

You make an input just like above to see a current a date auto selected